# JSON Schema for an array of values in a Rails API

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm gonna be flat out: The documentation for JSON Schema is shit. If someone could lead me to a link that shows otherwise, I'll gladly take a look and potentially change my opinion.

I've been spending the past 3 hours trying to get JSON Schema for the following VERY SIMPLE request/response:

When someone pings `/api/v1/payers?term=uni&max_results=6` the results they get are:

```
[
        {
           "label" : "United",
           "value" : "161a016e-8d06-49b9-9ddb-6bdbde248bcc"
        },
        {
           "label" : "United Healthcare",
           "value" : "1610426e-8de6-49b9-9ddb-6bfawf8bccew"
        }
]
```

I have the directory `docs/schema/schemata`. Do I have a `payer.json` in `schemata` that details ONE payer? Namely:

```
{
    "label" : "United",
    "value" : "161a016e-8d06-49b9-9ddb-6bdbde248bcc"
}
```

Then where do I define the array? Would that be in `schema.json` in the `schema` folder? Or... am I supposed to have a `payers.json` in `schemata`. I'm also using the `prmd` gem.

Nothing I read online leads me to an answer.

Comment: I agree the documentation is poor.  The Space Telescope Science Institute wrote an alternative: http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/

Comment: BTW, the first code-block in your answer isn't valid JSON.  Are you missing a property name?

Comment: Whoops, yeah, @cloudfeet it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

To specify a list of items, your schema should say:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {... item schema ...}
}
```

You could put the item schema inside the "items" property:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {...},
        "required": ["label", "value"]
    }
}
```

Or you could store it somewhere else and reference it using `$ref`:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/payer"},
    "definitions": {
        "payer": {
            "type": "object",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can also reference other schemas, so you can store the payer schema in a separate directory:

```
// payer-array.json
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {"$ref": "/schemas/payers.json"
}

// payers.json
{
    "type": "object",
    ...
}
```

So, in short: there are no limitations on where your schemas are stored, etc.  All that matters is that if you use a `$ref`, that it resolves correctly as a relative URL.